# why do I get this error when I try to run amplify push or pull often?

Tags: aws-lambda

this the error

```
const internalModuleReadJSON = function (f) { return require('fs').internalModuleReadJSON(f); };
                                                               ^

TypeError: require(...).internalModuleReadJSON is not a function
```

this error fixes itself randomly, sometimes it works, sometimes not,

sometimes I have to delete my project and then restart my pc but sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of your `NODE_OPTIONS` variable before running `amplify` - some tools (e.g. VS Code) may be setting this to a value that conflicts with something Amplify is doing.

If so, you can quickly (if clumsily) work around it by always running Amplify as `NODE_OPTIONS= amplify [push|pull|whatever]`.

See https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/10284

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because fs has no `InternalModuleReadJSON`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).